# On iOS, how do I resize a very large image on the client side in a web app?

Tags: javascript, ios, iphone, html, canvas

Using JavaScript and HTML5, you can take a `Image` class and draw it on a `canvas`, then redraw it pixel by pixel smaller  to another `canvas`. But if the image is too large, it will fail. By large, I mean `3500x2500` or `3.5mb` for the iPhone 4s through iPhone 6+

Unfortunately, the camera on the iPhone is taking images much larger than what appears to be resizable on the client. I cannot resize on the server, due to data constraints. Do I have any options?

Comment: are you taking the picture itself ? why not to specify the resolution through the API ? or is it a large image form the beginnning

Comment: if so you can easily do
var hdConstraints = {
  video: {
    mandatory: {
      minWidth: 1280,
      minHeight: 720
    }
  }
};

navigator.getUserMedia(hdConstraints, successCallback, errorCallback);

Comment: getUserMedia documentation says it's not supported on mobile Safari
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MediaDevices/getUserMedia

Answer (score 0):

I did find the Megapixel library that seems to correct this issue, though the documentation isn't clear that is it's purpose.

https://github.com/stomita/ios-imagefile-megapixel